# Image background removal tool for Windows (offline)

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

Background removal tools are possible: [Remove BG](https://www.remove.bg/) (online) works nicely, [Adobe](https://www.adobe.com/express/feature/image/remove-background) (online), [Removal AI](https://removal.ai/) (online; 1 free download only).

But they all don't fit my needs, which are:

- works offline
- works on Windows (10/11)
- is gratis, also for commercial use, granted by a real license
- removes the background of an image and saves it as a transparent images (PNG required)
- should work on high resolution images, like taken by a modern smartphone (>8Mpx)